# Remove small gap between nav and header

Tags: css, html, header, nav

My nav bar (*which is at the top of the page*) and header (*below nav, which has a large image and a text on top of it*), have a very small gap between them that I want to remove. I've visited a number of posts on similar problems, and tried their solutions, but can't seem to work for me, including: `display: block; margin: 0;` e.t.c.

I guess it has something to do with a style I have applied on either the header's content or the nav's content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: orange;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#bannerImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
 <img id="logo" src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/f607af5bc60d1b2837add83c70a2aa45/tumblr_inline_mrwv19q8fE1qz4rgp.gif"/>
 <li><a href="Game1.html" id="myBtn" onclick="disableLink()" >Game 1</a></li><li><a href="">Game 2</a></li><li><a href="">Game 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
 
<header>
  <img id="bannerImage" src="http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Hogwarts-lake.png"/>
  <h1>Games</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: remove the border (which is also putting a white line the whole way around the nav bar) and also the display:inline-block for the nav. That gets rid of all the white space around the nav bar.

Comment: Also a tip is that if you're opening the file in a browser like chrome, use inspect elements and then you can enable and disable stylings to see what each style is actually doing to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by your `ul` having `overflow:hidden` so just remove it.

Added `box-sizing:border-box` to avoid horizontal scrollbar

**UPDATE**

I noticed  that you have an `img` as child of `ul`  which makes that invalid HTML.

So I tweaked your code to make it valid.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top
}
nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: orange;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#bannerImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img id="logo" src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/f607af5bc60d1b2837add83c70a2aa45/tumblr_inline_mrwv19q8fE1qz4rgp.gif" />
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Game1.html" id="myBtn" onclick="disableLink()">Game 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Game 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Game 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header>
  <img id="bannerImage" src="http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Hogwarts-lake.png" />
  <h1>Games</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks dippas, both tips worked perfectly, I thought the horizontal scroll bar was to do with the width I had set or something hence I didn't ask about that. What does the * in '* {box-sizing: border-box}' represent?

Comment: Just noticed now that you have an image as child of `ul` that's invalid HTML. I'm going to update the answer

Comment: @Sat10 if you want, you can look at the updated answer with valid HTML

Comment: But now when I hover my cursor over the nav buttons, there is a gap below it.

Comment: @Sat10, my bad I forgot to add `vertical-align:top` to `#logo` , elements with `inline-block` are by default `vertical-align:baseline`

Answer (score 1):

Just define the height of `nav`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden!important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 51px;
}
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: orange;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
#bannerImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
 <img id="logo" src="https://67.media.tumblr.com/f607af5bc60d1b2837add83c70a2aa45/tumblr_inline_mrwv19q8fE1qz4rgp.gif"/>
 <li><a href="Game1.html" id="myBtn" onclick="disableLink()" >Game 1</a></li><li><a href="">Game 2</a></li><li><a href="">Game 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
 
<header>
  <img id="bannerImage" src="http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Hogwarts-lake.png"/>
  <h1>Games</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the nav:

```
nav {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Tried it out and works even without the margin set to 0.